# mysql left join limit not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

basically what I'm trying to do is limit my responses to 5 per comment in my query

**My following query**

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.comment, 
replies.id reply_id, replies.comment_id, replies.reply
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM replies LIMIT 3) replies 
ON comments.id = replies.comment_id
WHERE comments.user_id = ? ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 3

$comments = array();
$comm_replies = array();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$comm_id = $row['id'];
$comm_user_id = $row['user_id']; 
$comm = $row['comment'];

if (empty($row['reply_id'])) {
  continue;    
}

$comments[$comm_id] = $comm;
$comm_replies[$comm_id][] = $row;
}

foreach ($comments as $comm_id => $comm) {
echo "comment - $comm\n";
if (!isset($comm_replies[$comm_id])) {
    continue;
}

$prefix = '---';
foreach ($comm_replies[$comm_id] as $reply_id => $row) {
    echo "$prefix $row['reply_id'], $row['reply']\n";
    $prefix .= '-';
}
}
```

**So what I'm trying to output is the following:**

1.Question One
---First Response
---Second Response
---Third Response

2.Question Two
---First Response
---Second Response
---Third Response

3.Question Three
---First Response
---Second Response
---Third Response

**Instead What i get is this:**

1.Question One
---First Response
---Second Response

I'm not sure why its out putting just the first question and 2 responds.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is wrong:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM replies LIMIT 3) replies
```

You must be specific and define the parameters for these findings in an enclosure WHERE

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id FROM replies a WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @gpupo But, I'm not following you... do you mean like this... LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comments.id = replies.comment_id LIMIT 3) because this does not work for me unfortunately